# What would be the value of VkAccessFlags for a VkBuffer or VkImage after being allocated memory?

Tags: vulkan

So I create a bunch of buffers and images, and I need to set up a memory barrier for some reason.

How do I know what to specify in the `srcAccessMask` field for the barrier struct of a newly created buffer or image, seeing as at that point I wouldn't have specified the access flags for it? How do I decide what initial access flags to specify for the first memory barrier applied to a buffer or image?

Specifying initial values for other parameters in `Vk*MemoryBarrier` is easy since I can clearly know, say, the original layout of an image, but it isn't apparent to me what the value of `srcAccessMask` could be the first time I set up a barrier.

Is it based on the usage flags specified during creation of the object concerned? Or is there some other way that can be used to find out?

Comment: Barriers exist to synchronize access between two operations on a piece of memory (interpreted through a resource). So... what is the starting operation that you want this barrier to be between? You're synchronizing between A and B, such that B cannot proceed until A is done. What is A?

Comment: @NicolBolas If he (or she) knew what A is, he/she wouldn't ask this question ;-).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, let's assume `vkCreateImage` and `VK_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED`.

Nowhere the specification says it defines some scheduled *operation*. So it is healthy to assume all its work is done as soon as it returns. Plus, it does not even have memory.

So any synchronization needs would be of the memory you bind to it. Let's assume it is just fresh memory from `vkAllocate`. Similarly, nowhere it is said in the specification that it defines some scheduled *operation*.

Even so, there's really only two options. Either the implementation does nothing with the memory, or it null-fills it (for security reason). In the case it null-fills it, that must be done in a way you cannot access the original data (even using synchronization errors). So it is healthy to assume the memory has no "synchronization baggage" on it.

So simply `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` (no previous outstanding scheduled operation) and `srcAccessMask = 0` (no previous writes) should be correct.

Comment: I just checked the `VkAccessFlagBits` enum, and now I see that `0` is not used for anything, so I guess it can be used to say nothing was done previously...

Comment: @WarpspeedSCP No need to guess. 0 is a legitimate value (as is doing only one-half of a memory dependency).

Comment: What do you mean by half a memory dependency?

Comment: @WarpspeedSCP A pipeline barrier defines two-halves of a memory dependency. One makes a resource *available-from* and second makes it *visible-to*. If you have a resource that is already available, or you will make visible some other way, you only need a half of that memory dependency. The half that is skipped will have the `*AccessMask = 0` (and likely accompanied by `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT` or `dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT`).